# how to set time interval in app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How do you set time interval before the events occurs in google app engine? like I want to give the users 3 seconds to read the warnings before they are redirected to some pages. like there is 3 second pause before self.redirect("/"). Thank you

Comment: This would have to be handled client side. Look at using setTimeout() in javascript or the <META> refresh tag. This is not really app engine specific.

Comment: I am just new here and dont know how to accept answer, tell me how please, thank you

Comment: Click on the big checkmark next to the answer you like. It will turn green.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have a pause on the client-side before redirecting to a different page, you need to do that on the client side, so it will have nothing to do with AppEngine directly.

You can create such an effect with a meta refresh tag in the `<head>` section of your page:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL=redirect_page.htm">
```

In the content attribute, the `3` is the number of seconds to wait, and `redirect_page.htm` is the URL to which you want the user to go after the pause.

Comment: Is there a way to ensure the page only redirects when the post method is executed (and not when app engine fetches the page)?

Comment: I believe that you would have to use JavaScript to achieve such an effect.